# How configure Intellij Idea javadoc templates?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, auto-generate, live-templates

I have some method:

```
public int getSomeField()
```

I want to generate javadoc like this:

```
/**
* Gets {someField}
*
* @return value of {someField}
*/
```

Where {someField} is placeholder for field name. It is possible to create this templates for Intellij Idea (may be as live template)?

Comment: If you were using Eclipse I'd recommend [JAutoDoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 35):

Bring up the Generate menu (Cmd+N on Mac, Alt+Insert on Windows)

[image: Generate menu]

Click the ellipsis in the top right hand corner.

[image: Generate Getters menu]

Click the plus in the top left corner and create a new template.
[image: Create new template dialog]

Copy the contents of the old template into the new template and add the following lines to the top of it.

```
/**
* Gets $field.name
*
* @return value of $field.name
*/
```

[image]

Now when you generate the getter use the 'New Template' and you should get your getter with the JavaDoc.

[image: Select New Template]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You generate Javadoc by placing the caret above the method. Then you type `/**` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Unfortunately the template can't be changed and there is a request for that: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-28206

Comment: You can now edit comments on templates. See the answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38094408/2377639

Answer (score 9):

This will get you most of the way there.

`File | Settings... | Live Templates`

Press the green plus to add a new custom template.

Abbrevation: `getter`

Template text:

```
/**
 * Gets $FIELD$
 *
 * @return value of $FIELD$
 */
public $RET$ get$FIELD$()
{
    $END$
}
```

Applicable in Java: `declaration`.

Type `getter` where you would a method and `tab` complete.

The only shortcoming is I don't know how to make the first character of `$FIELD$` capitalized in `get$FIELD$` but none of the other locations.

Here is an image for reference:

[image: IntelliJ Template "getter"]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate the JavaDoc *after* the method was written (using `/**`), there is currently no way to customize this. Vote for issue [IDEA-97658: Edit template for javadoc stub](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-97658) if you'd like to see this implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can add a live template for such javadoc. The easiest way to do it is to select the whole comment and invoke "Save as live template" action (Tools menu). See http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the methodName() expression, but this only works while inside a method, you want the method outside of it, in the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, to change the setter template in a similar fashion you can add this:

```
/**
 * Sets $field.name
 *
 * @param $paramName value of $field.name
 */
```

after the `#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))` line.

This will take into account the potential parameter prefix/suffix rules from the project config.