# IntelliJ shortcut to create default javadoc for getter and setter methods

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a feature in IntelliJ to create getter and setter methods with javadoc surrounded? We have this feature in eclipse where getter and setters for a variable is created with javadoc. Eclipse provides an option to create javadoc by its own. Is there something similar in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no built-in method to achieve this.
But [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6120?pr=idea) is a link to a plugin that should do it for you.

Regards.

Comment: I installed Javadoc Utility plugin into my IntelliJ and that works now. Thank you :)

Comment: Javadoc Utility does not work with IDEA 2016. Here's the built in alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607925/how-configure-intellij-idea-javadoc-templates