# Customize Javadoc template in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

When I type "/** + Enter" above a method in Android Studio,  it automatically generates this Javadoc for me.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param xInt
 * @param xString
 * @param xBoolean
 * @return
 */
public static String someMethod(int xInt, String xString, boolean xBoolean) {

    if (xString == Integer.toString(xInt) == xBoolean) {
        return "all are equal";
    }

    return "a string";
}
```

I want to change the JavaDoc template, so that when I type "/** + Enter", it will automatically generate this:

```
/**
 * Explanation of Method here 
 *
 * @param xInt     Interger Explanation here
 * @param xString  String   Explanation here
 * @param xBoolean Boolean  Explanation here
 * @return Explanation Here
 */
```

Comment: doesn't look very promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607925/how-configure-intellij-idea-javadoc-templates

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607925/how-configure-intellij-idea-javadoc-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to customize the JavaDocs template. This is done automatically by Android Studio based on the method signature.