# Change template for JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, javadoc

How can I change the template for JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA? I want override the existing template that you get, if you type in "/**" and press "return"-key.

This is what I get currently:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param parameter1
 * @param parameter2
 */
```

And this is what I want:

```
/**
 * @author sheldon
 *
 * @date 29.06.2016
 *
 * @param parameter1
 * @param parameter2
 */
```

Please help!

Comment: Have a look here. It describes how to add a JavaDoc comment to a generated Getter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38094408/2377639

Comment: Thanks for answer! I want to create a template for all methods. I want to type in " /** " --> press "return"-key and javadoc will generate above the method (like in eclipse)

Comment: I couldn't find a way to override the /** template. I found this article http://artfulonline.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/quick-logging-with-intellij-live.html which details how to create a live template but I couldn't get the param part to work. You would also need to use a different shortcut.

Comment: There is an open feature request here so I am not sure what you want is possible. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128817#tab=Comments&u=1464015199700