# how to customise the generated documentation template using intelij-javadoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using this plugin to generate javadoc documentation in InteliJ idea.

https://github.com/setial/intellij-javadocs/wiki

The wiki mentions template variables, but I am reasonably new to intelij, so need some more step by step instructions on how to go about customising the generated documentation.

I want to remove the space between the description and variable(s).

```
/**
 * Gets task pool configuration id.
 *
 * @return the task pool configuration id
 */
public Long getTaskPoolConfigurationId() {
    return taskPoolConfigurationId;
}
```

to this

```
/**
 * Gets task pool configuration id.
 * @return the task pool configuration id
 */
public Long getTaskPoolConfigurationId() {
    return taskPoolConfigurationId;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607925/how-configure-intellij-idea-javadoc-templates

Comment: this shows how to change the generated code for the actual getter, which doesn't show the comments. The generator I am trying to change is the intelij-javadocs generator which generates the comments. It doesn't seem to be the same template at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this here:

- Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)

  - Editor

    - Code Style

      - Java

        - "JavaDoc" tab

          - Toggle off "Blank Lines - After Description"

Comment: is there a way to change the template completely? Just curious.