# In IDEA, how to generate javadoc for new type?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

In Eclipse, `alt + shift + J` on a new type, will generate javadoc with author & date.

e.g

```
/**
 * @author eric
 * @date Apr 3, 2015 8:49:31 PM
 */
```

In IDEA, I tried, but it just generate an empty Javadoc without author or date.

e.g

```
/**
 * 
 */
```

**The question is:**

- In IDEA, how to generate a javadoc same as Eclipse does, with the author & date part?
- Is it possible to generate it automatically on type creation?
- What is the default shortcut for that?

---

### @Update - summary

According to comment and answer, following javadoc is added to file template:

```
/**
 * @author ${USER}
 * @date ${DATE} ${TIME}
 */
```

for file type: `Class`, `Interface`, `Enum`, `AnnotationType`.

The javadoc will be added on type creation automatically.
But still seems there is no shortcut to add it by hand for existing types.

Comment: You should customize file templates : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For classes, interfaces, etc., you can edit File Template: `Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates`.

```
/**
 * @author Eric
 * @date ${DATE}
 */
```

For methods, that can be generated (like getters, setters) you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38094408/3124227

For methods there is no functionality to edit javadoc: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97658

Comment: Ok, I have solved it. BTW, there are more placeholders `${USER}` for system user name, `${DATE} {TIME}` to get both date & time, and I apply this to `Class`, `Interface`, `Enum`, `AnnotationType`, now it works very similar as in Eclipse.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to? This is precisely the kind of information that a version control system helps you track! For example, you can get this from Git by running `git log --diff-filter=A --follow path/to/my/Class.java`.

(Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598028 for the specific snippet.)

To be clear, I'm not against Javadoc as a whole, only using it to manually track information that is automatically tracked elsewhere.

Comment: The issue in the question intends to help while viewing source code, not actually relevant to any version control system, that's another story.

Comment: And, when you publish the code as jar, the user don't necessary have access to scm like Git, that's when javadoc is even more important to get information like this.

Comment: @EricWang If you can give them a source code dump then you can give them SCM access. That said, this is not particularly useful as an external user anyway. In that case I care about things like the version number where it was added, not which date.